# Where Did I make a mistake in my deviation for the Period of a Pendulum Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, physics

Imagine a Pendulum with String Length L,   and Angle θ, which forms arclength S (Will be used later in the derivation.)

First V  =  $\sqrt{2gh} $ (Height is measured straight down) KNOWN TO BE A CORRECT FORMULA

(From Here, Assume that nothing else is  proven to be correct.)

Arclength X = $Lθ $

Time (Period ) = T

V = $(Distance) / (Time)$

V =  $Lθ/T $
$\sqrt{2gh} = \frac{4Lθ}{T} $ (Four, as the pendulum covers that area four times)

Height $= L - L \cos θ$

$\sqrt{2gL(1 - cos(θ))} = \frac{4Lθ}{T} $

$T = \frac{4Lθ}{\sqrt{2gL(1 - cos(θ))}}  $

This is very different from the known period of a  (simple) Pendulum $T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L} {g}}    $, mainly where the angle  $\theta $ doesn't even exist.  Is there a way to get  the canceled    $\theta $ in my derived equation to cancel out?  Did I just completely make a  Mistake?

Comment: A good hint that something is not right is that the period of a pendulum is a property of the system itself, not a particular state. That is, it shouldn't depend on the angle $\theta$.

Comment: I am looking for  some way to cancel Theta, as I know that ti shouldn't be there.  I can't figure out a way for it to cancel out   tho.

Comment: @kyotiq I do not think that that V (average velocity of pendulum) can simply be taken to be $\sqrt{2gh}$, as the velocity of the pendulum is not constant, which could be why this derivation does not work. On the other hand, $\theta$ can probably be cancelled through small angle approximation.

Comment: $\sqrt{2gh}$ is the maximum speed (at the lowest point or mean position). You seem to be using it as the average speed.

Comment: @K.Jiang -- _"That is, it shouldn't depend on the angle θ"_ but it does. In contrast to a spring-mass system the reacting force is **not** linear proportional to deflection.

Comment: @m-stgt The *period* of a pendulum certainly does not depend on $\theta = \theta (t)$, which is the angle of deflection that varies with time. Sure, for large enough oscillations, the period depends on the initial conditions, say, $T = f (\theta_\text{max})$, but *not* on $\theta (t)$.

Answer (score 1):

The original derivation takes $\theta$ to be small so $1-\cos\theta\approx{\theta^2\over 2}$ your answer becomes $$T=4\sqrt{L\over g}$$

Now your mistake is $v={s\over t}$ because this only works when velocity doesn't change (acceleration = 0) but velocity depends on height and height changes

I'll prove it here for reference a fair background in rotational mechanics would help

Taking polar coordinates we $r=L$ and $\theta$ (angle with vertical) varies

From rudimentary circular motion with fixed $r$ using torque equation about the point of contact we get
$$
mr^2{d^2\theta\over dt^2}=-mgr\sin\theta
$$
The gravity component is taken perpendicular to string as tension cancels the other component

Now nothing stops you from directly integration for $\theta(t)$ but this comes out as elliptic integrals and other fun stuff to avoid that we approximate $\sin\theta\approx\theta$

This is the general SHM
$${d^2\theta\over dt^2}=-{g\over L}\theta$$
Which solves to
$$\theta(t)=A\sin\left(\sqrt{g\over L}t+\phi\right)$$

The period of this function is $$T=2\pi\sqrt{L\over g}$$

Answer (score 1):

**1. What went wrong?** The formula

$$\text{speed}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}} $$

actually defines the **average speed**, whereas your formula $v=\sqrt{2gh}$ is the maximum instantaneous speed of the bob (when it passes through the minimum height point). This means that you cannot directly plug $v$ to the above formula.

**2. What is correct?** In fact, the period of a (not-approximated) pendulum is given by

$$T = \frac{4}{\omega} K\left(\sin\frac{\theta_0}{2}\right),$$

where

- $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$ is the angular frequency of corresponding simple pendulum,
- $K(k) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac {\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{1 - k^{2}\sin^{2} \theta}}$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind), and
- $\theta_0$ is the maximum angular displacement.

When $\theta_0$ is small, this is approximated by the usual formula for the simple pendulum:

$$ \theta_0 \ll 1 \qquad\implies\qquad T \approx \frac{2\pi}{\omega} = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}. $$

Check [this page](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/A_First_Course_in_Differential_Equations_for_Scientists_and_Engineers_(Herman)/07%3A_Nonlinear_Systems/7.09%3A_The_Period_of_the_Nonlinear_Pendulum) for the derivation.